# If Not Statement not working Properly Within a Loop in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create and `IF NOT` statement within a loop. I wish to make it so, that if that cell does not have the values I am looking for a formula gets inserted in another column of the same row. Right now the If not statement is being ignored and all the cells get the formula.

```
Sub Example()
Dim Sales As Range
Dim cell As Range

lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

Set Sales= Workbooks("Sales.xlsm").Sheets("Sales").Range("B2:B" & lr)

 For Each cell In Sales



    If Not cell.Value = "Monday" Or cell.Value = "Tuesday" Then

    cell.Offset(0, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*RC[-1]"



    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `If cell.Value <> "Monday" And cell.Value <> "Tuesday" Then`.

Comment: `If Not (Cell.Value = "Monday") or (Cell.Value = "Tuesday") Then`. It seems that your second condition is missing the `Not`. However, ultimately all testing is done for True. Therefore @BigBen's suggestion is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the simplest method:

`If (Cell.Value2 <> "Monday") Then`

Tip: you don't need the OR for the second condition because its always met with the first condition.

In other words, (Cell.Value2 <> "Monday") will make the 2nd condition obsolete because it will always be true if the day is not Monday.

**Edit:**

I think @BigBen is correct, you want to exclude Mondays **and** Tuesdays, so:

```
If cell.Value <> "Monday" And cell.Value <> "Tuesday" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to determine if a single string value can be one of a number of string values then I would use the Instr method.

```
Dim Days as string
Days = "Monday,Tuesday"
If Instr(Days, cell.Value)=0 then
```